# Unable to configure Live Stream in Application Insights for ASP Core application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have configured Application Insights in my application and I am receiving telemetry. However, when I click the Live Metrics Stream page I am getting: "Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK".

How do I get Live Stream to appear?

Comment: Not available yet but almost there, see https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/pull/518 and https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to activate it in code, even though it's not yet supported officially. In Startup.cs add following code:

```
        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
        configuration.InstrumentationKey = "e73ee2c9-776t-er45-4244-b2139c6dc724";
        QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor processor = null;
        configuration.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
            .Use((next) =>
            {
                processor = new QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor(next);
                return processor;
            })
            .Build();
        var QuickPulse = new QuickPulseTelemetryModule();
        QuickPulse.Initialize(configuration);
        QuickPulse.RegisterTelemetryProcessor(processor);
```

Add Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector

Based on the following [post](http://apmtips.com/blog/2017/02/13/enable-application-insights-live-metrics-from-code/).

Comment: I think this is for .NET Classic only

Comment: No it is not. I have it running with my asp core app.

Answer (score 2):

Live Metrics isn't yet supported from the ASP.Net Core packages.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/216

though given this PR it looks like it might be close?

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/pull/518

Comment: Yes. .NET Core support for Live Metrics is coming soon.